# Is there any final even happen before a XF application exits for ever?

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms

I realize there are these events:

```
    protected override void OnSleep()
    {
        base.OnSleep();
    }

    protected override void OnResume()
    {
        base.OnResume();
    }
```

But is there any event that is called in which I could perform a logging action, before the app is finally swiped out of view and closed?

Comment: there is no method for application termination,for UWP, the OnSleep() is called, when i close the App.

Comment: @Cherry Bu - Okay I understand what you are saying.  But at least for Android and iOS would that OnSleep happen (perhaps many times if OnResume happened) if the app was moved into the background or closed?

Comment: The documentation i linked specifically says:


```Note

There is no method for application termination. Under normal circumstances (i.e. not a crash) application termination will happen from the OnSleep state, without any additional notifications to your code.```

Answer (score 1):

No there are only 3 lifecycle events for a Xamarin.Forms application. See [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/app-fundamentals/app-lifecycle). They are:

`OnStart()`, `OnSleep()`, and `OnResume()`.

What you could do is just do whatever you need to in `OnSleep` and reverse it in `OnResume`. That way whether the user comes back or not, you've handled what you need to handle.

Answer (score 1):

No, and it is technically impossible to make something like that on iOS and Android. On UWP you could make some native code that would invoke this on Xamarin.Forms project. But I don't think that anyone is interested in such UWP only feature on Xamarin.Forms, so if you need it you will probably need to implement it yourself.